# Reusable Cell isn't calling prepareForReuse function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Ok, need a little help here. I'm new to Swift. Here's my issue.

When getting data for my UITableView, I'm calling image data from a url, so there is a slight delay when grabbing reused cells, resulting in the cell showing old data for half a second. I've tried to call func prepareForReuse to reset properties, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help is appreciated!

Here's my code when calling cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.alpha = 0
    let book = books[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = book.bookTitle
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = book.postURL
    let url = URL(string: book.postPicture)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.alpha = 0
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data!))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
    cell.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;

    func prepareForReuse(){
        cell.alpha = 0
        cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "book.jpg"))
    }
    return cell


}
```

Comment: You can't override `prepareForReuse` that way. You have to subclass `UITableViewCell` and override it in the subclass declaration. And you'll need to typecast the result of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` to your subclass. Also, technically you should be downloading your images to disk first asynchronously and then loading them from disk into your image view while the user scrolls.

Comment: Ok, do you have an example of how that would work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should subclass UITableView cell and inside your custom class override:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        // your cleanup code
    }
}
```

then in UITableViewDataSource method reuse the custom cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is in a UITableViewController, but i also have the data parser in the same class. could that cause an issue? Also, if I put the override func outside of the tableview function, i get "Method does not override any method from its superclass", and "use of unresolved identifier 'cell'"

Comment: Hold on. I think my issue is that I'm stuffing it all in a CONTROLLER and not CELL..... Let me double check this real quick.

Comment: @Garyb99 Exactly ;] You need to override the method inside the cell, not in the controller.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now successfully calling the function. Now another question. How do you change the cell properties from here? If I type in "Cell.(insert code here)" then it gives me "use of unresolved identifier cell"

Comment: @Garyb99 strongly advise you to read Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell, it's the best source of info on APIs. 
Also checkout these guides:
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/791/uitableview/6711/custom-table-view-cell#t=201703161939197248432

Comment: @Garyb99 please describe the problem you have, the result you want to achieve and post your code ;]

Comment: Ok, so I have the code that I posted in original question in my TableViewController class. I have now moved my prepareForReuse into a TableViewCell. I want to be able to change a cell's opacity and background picture back to default in the Reuse function using "cell.alpha = 0" but it tells me that Cell is an unresolved identifier

Comment: @Garyb99 if you are in the subclass of the cell you just type alpha = 0.0 (or self.alpha = 0.0), you don't need "cell"

Comment: Oh I'm such an idiot. Of course it isn't needed. Thanks a bunch, solves all my problems!

Comment: @Garyb99 hey, we've all been there. try to read documentation carefully and you'll be able to do stuff. Good luck ;]